# What happens after Zombieslayer?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, gotrek-felix

At the end of [Zombieslayer](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7841525-zombieslayer), when Felix is asked what himself and Gotrek will do next, he says something to the effect of:

> we need to take [Snorri Nosebiter](http://be.convdocs.org/pars_docs/refs/71/70486/70486_html_2c6aa56f.jpg) on his pilgrimage in order to recover his Doom.

Zombieslayer is the final Gotrek and Felix book written by Nathan Long. The following books and short stories are by Josh Reynolds and then various authors after that.

Are the events Felix refers to covered in any book? I haven't been able to find it and I think I've read close to everything after Zombieslayer, bar [Kinslayer](http://www.blacklibrary.com/Warhammer/gotrek-felix-kinslayer-hardback.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion to the story of Snorri Nosebiter does occur in Kinslayer. Previously Snorri had forgotten his shame and the reason he became a slayer. In this book it is revealed along with if he in fact finds his doom. I do not recommend looking at the spoiler below as it may ruin the story for you, but I will supply it as proof of answer to this question.

>  Snorri's saga culminates in Kinslayer, where we finally find out Snorri's shame: he blames himself for Gotrek getting lost during their attempt to return back from their failed expedition to the Chaos Wastes, which he talked Gotrek into going on. And he also blames himself, implicitly quite rightly, for the destruction of Gotrek's home village by Goblins, because he got drunk and addled and had a fight with some dwarven rangers who were trying to stop the raiding party, meaning he may have prevented them from warning the village. Finally, he made his way to the village after it was destroyed: Gotrek's wife had survived the goblin raid, but Snorri got confused when she emerged from the burned ruins and cut her down, as he mistook her for a goblin that had stayed behind. And then Snorri's doom comes in the wake of this: he confesses his shame to Gotrek, and allows his old friend to kill him. Not just allows; the two Slayers actually fight to the death, Gotrek utterly furious and Snorri sobbing in shame and anguish the whole time.

Comment: Ah, cheers! Much appreciated!